# Bind Objects with generic list to wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, list, datagrid

I like to display my data objects:

```
class DataElement
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<customProperty> properties { get; set; }
}

class customProperty
{
    public String value;
    public String definition;
}
```

in a datagrid like:

```
Name                    | dataElementList[0].properties[0].definiton | dataElementList[0].properties[1].definiton | dataElementList[0].properties[2].definiton | ...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
dataElementList[0].Name | dataElementList[0].properties[0].value     | dataElementList[0].properties[1].value     | dataElementList[0].properties[2].value     | ...
dataElementList[1].Name | dataElementList[1].properties[0].value     | dataElementList[1].properties[1].value     | dataElementList[1].properties[2].value     | ...
....
```

The property definition are the same for all elements.
How can i bind my data structures to a datagrid with CellTemplates?

Comment: Did you have a look on DataTemplate?

Comment: sure, it is about how to transpose the values as single column header.